# How to get records based on 2 criterias

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I want to get the record based on highest score and minimum time taken

```
SELECT user.id, user.first_name, user.last_name, quiz.id, quiz.name, user_quiz_history.score, user_quiz_history.time_taken
FROM user_quiz_history
JOIN user ON user.id = user_quiz_history.user_id
JOIN quiz ON quiz.id = user_quiz_history.quiz_id WHERE score =
    (SELECT MAX(score)
    FROM user_quiz_history
    WHERE quiz_id = $id)
GROUP BY quiz_id
ORDER BY quiz_id dESC
```

With this query I am getting the expected result but with MAX(score) only.

There are certain scenarios where scores are equals so I have to differential on the basis of less time taken.

In this case it picks up the 1st record of the two records having same score but differents time_taken.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can order by score and time in your subquery and limit 1

```
SELECT ...
JOIN quiz ON quiz.id = user_quiz_history.quiz_id
WHERE user_quiz_history.id =
    (SELECT qh.id
    FROM user_quiz_history qh
    WHERE qh.quiz_id = $id
    ORDER BY qh.score DESC,
             qh.time_taken ASC
    LIMIT 1)
...;
```

Comment: Thanks alot it worked for me #Cid i have marked your answer as a correct